# Haml - adding a display:none to a p tag isn't working

Tags: css, haml

I am trying to do this:

```
  %p{:style=>"display:none;"}
    %h4= t("labels.shortened_urls.fqdn_url")
    =f.url_field :fqdn_url, {:readonly => true}
    %small=link_to((t "links.shortened_urls.view"), :target => :_blank)
```

but I can not get it to stop displaying. Is there something I am not doing correctly with the first line there?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have to use inline styles here? Could you just create a css class with display:none property and apply that to the paragraph?

Comment: @ply yes I could but it might still not work since I am not sure why it is not working here :)

Comment: hmm...can you post the source from the view template when it is rendered in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Haml is correct, in that it generates the style attribute correctly, but your HTML is wrong. A `h4` element is not allowed as a direct child of a `p` element, so the browser implicitly closes the `p` before the `h4`. In effect you hava an empty `p`, which has `display:none` set.

Try changing the `p` to a `div`, which is allowed to have `h4` as a child. (You might want to alter the other contents too).